# Playwright: how to watch locator state changes

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I have the following code to test a pin code overlay:

```js
...
const pinInput = page.locator('[data-test="pin"] >> input');
await pinInput.waitFor();
expect(await pinInput.count()).toBe(1);
await pinInput.fill(pinCode);
...
```

However the pin code overlay appears on the page multiple times and it would be nice if I can somehow watch the state of the pin locator and enter the pin every time the overlay appears.

A pseudocode can look something like this:

```js
...
const pinInput = page.locator('[data-test="pin"] >> input');
pinInput.watch(async state => {
  if (state === 'visible') {
    expect(await pinInput.count()).toBe(1);
    await pinInput.fill(pinCode);
  }
});
...
```

Comment: Do you have the site itself or a representative example of the site? It's sort of hard to help without seeing what we're dealing with and being able to run and test the code. Thanks.

Comment: When should the test complete? What is the condition after which you don't expect overlays to show up anymore?